# OpenSSL signing and CAPI verification

Tags: c++, com, openssl, mscapi

I'm working with CAPICOM libary, but it is not available on Android and iOS. As far as i know, CAPICOM signed message is in PKCS#7 format, then i want to use OpenSSL to create signed message like CAPICOM did.

The OpenSSL commands i used:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le data.bin > data-utf16le.bin

openssl smime -sign -binary -noattr -in data-utf16le.bin -signer demo.pem -inkey demo.key -out sign.txt -outform PEM
```

then i verified with CAPICOM as this sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9691/Using-CAPICOM-in-NET-for-Digital-Signatures-with-A

The verify method is:

```
public bool VerifyDetachedSignature(string plaintextMessage, string signedContent, Encoding encodingType) 
{
    try
    {
        this._clearText = plaintextMessage;
        this._signedContent = signedContent;
        CAPICOM.SignedData signedData = new CAPICOM.SignedDataClass();
        CAPICOM.Utilities u = new CAPICOM.UtilitiesClass();
        IntPtr _content = u.ByteArrayToBinaryString(encodingType.GetBytes(plaintextMessage));
                signedData.set_Content(_content);
        int len = _signedContent.Length;
        signedData.Verify(_signedContent,true, CAPICOM.CAPICOM_SIGNED_DATA_VERIFY_FLAG.CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_ONLY);
        SignerCert=null;
        CAPICOM.Signer s = (CAPICOM.Signer) signedData.Signers[1];
        SignerCert = (CAPICOM.Certificate)s.Certificate;                
        return true;                    
    }
    catch(COMException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`encodingType` is `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.

The result is invalid.

I sign again with CAPICOM and i saw that the length of signed message in this case is longer than the length of signed message created by OpenSSL.

Please help me to understand!

Comment: *`iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le data.bin > data-utf16le.bin`* - Binary data is ***not*** necessarily well formed UTF-8 or UTF-16. The conversion will likely fail on occasion. If you need a presentation format, then use Base64, Base32 or Hex (base16) encoding.

Comment: Thank you, although i used this openssl command:

`openssl smime -sign -binary -noattr -in data-utf16le.bin -signer demo.pem -inkey demo.key -out sign.txt -outform PEM`, CAPICOM library still return invalid result.

Comment: Now i know that CAPICOM's signature include certificate chain and this is the reason why its lenght is longer than the lenght of OpenSSL's signature. How do i create signature with attached certificate chain by OpenSSL?